# Incomplete error with the TukeyHSD function in R and unsure how to fix it

Tags: r, statistics

I am working with the morley data. I am doing randomized block experiment with Run as the treatment factor and Expt as the blocking factor. I need to identify if there a difference between runs and what efficiency is gained by blocking.

The code I used to solve this problem is:

```
library(multcomp)
library(faraway)
data(morley)
treatment = morley$Run
blocking = morley$Expt
modelfit = lm(Speed~treatment+blocking, morley)
summary(modelfit)
anova(modelfit)
TukeyHSD(aov(Speed~treatment+factor(blocking), factory(morley))$treatment
```

The problem I am running into is with the TukeyHSD function specifically. It gives me this error:

> "Error: Incomplete expression:
>   TukeyHSD(aov(Speed~treatment+factor(blocking),
>   factory(morley))$treatment"

I am unsure how to fix this because I have used a similar method in the past and it has worked. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Check the parantheses on that command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable speed was not called into the dataset in your code.

```
Speed = morley$Speed
```

Are you trying for this?

```
> TukeyHSD(aov(Speed~treatment+factor(blocking)))
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = Speed ~ treatment + factor(blocking))

$`factor(blocking)`
     diff        lwr        upr     p adj
2-1 -53.0 -118.61406  12.614058 0.1719005
3-1 -64.0 -129.61406   1.614058 0.0595018
4-1 -88.5 -154.11406 -22.885942 0.0027517
5-1 -77.5 -143.11406 -11.885942 0.0121938
3-2 -11.0  -76.61406  54.614058 0.9901489
4-2 -35.5 -101.11406  30.114058 0.5619434
5-2 -24.5  -90.11406  41.114058 0.8367799
4-3 -24.5  -90.11406  41.114058 0.8367799
5-3 -13.5  -79.11406  52.114058 0.9787898
5-4  11.0  -54.61406  76.614058 0.9901489
```